# How to extract different metrics from source code in Enterprise Architect

Tags: reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect, code-metrics

I have source code of a project (multiple files) that I have exported as source directory in the Enterprise Architect. I want to use the EA for the following.

- Extract different source code metrics such as LOC, Comments, No of classes etc.
- Extract function calls.
- Extract level of coupling between classes.
- Detect code smells.

However, I have been looking through different forums and documentation files for days and haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Architect doesn't have the functions you are looking for. It's basically not the right tool for that job.

You might be able to do something if you write a bunch of scripts, or an add-in. But in that case you would basically need to parse and interpret the code yourself.

What you are looking for is a static code analysis tool, not a modelling tool such as EA.

Comment: Actually my professor asked specifically to use Enterprise Architect for the above mentioned tasks.  So I have no other option.

Comment: Do you have another option, and that is to tell your professor that this task will take at least a year to complete in EA, and also that there are alternatives that do this out of the box. If he specifically asked to do it in MS-Paint, would you still try it?

Comment: His previous students have done that, by making a database model of source code and then applying SQL quires on the tables through script in visual studio. That is all he told us.

Comment: And how is any of that related to EA?

Comment: @ Geert Bellekens database model was created in EA. Through some coding in the EA.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com), it gives you all these metrics and features and it's free for open source contributors.

Comment: Thanks, for your response, however, I am going to check JArchitect.  However, I have a graduate assignment that must only me completed in EA!